# Delete element from state arrays through method passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main component, App.js, with the following state.

```
  state = {
    cats: [
      { id: '1', name: 'Cat 1'},
      { id: '2', name: 'Cat 2'},
      { id: '3', name: 'Cat 3'},
    ],
    dogs: [
      { id: '1', name: 'Dog 1'},
      { id: '2', name: 'Dog 2'},
    ],
    birds: [
      { id: '1', name: 'Bird 1'},
    ]
  }
```

Also, in the same component a method (now just consoling the index) and the imported component that list the animals.
Method:

```
  deleteAnimalHandler = (index) => {
    console.log(index)
  }
```

JSX or return:

```
<div>
  <AnimalList deleteAnimal={this.deleteAnimalHandler} animal={this.state.cats} />
  <AnimalList deleteAnimal={this.deleteAnimalHandler} animal={this.state.dogs} />
  <AnimalList deleteAnimal={this.deleteAnimalHandler} animal={this.state.birds} />
</div>
```

In AnimalList component I´m mapping the props and rendering the lists.

```
{props.animal.map(({id, name}, index) =>
  <div key={id}><div>{name}</div><div onClick={() => props.deleteAnimal(index)}>Delete animal</div></div>
  )
}
```

Every time I click on the div with content "Delete animal" I´m executing the deleteTaskHandler() method and logging in the console the index of that element in the array.

What I´m trying to do of course is not logging into the console, if not, when I click on that div, delete in the particular property of the state the element with the passed index.

So, if I click in Delete animal below Cat 2 I should delete Cat 2 from the cats array. The same for dogs and birds.

I cannot find the logic to let the handler know which is the context or which should be the array that setState() should update.

Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass category of the animal too.

```
deleteAnimalHandler = (index,category) => {
      let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state))
      temp[category] = temp[category].filter(({id})=> id !== index )

     // you can set state now
}
```

Here you can pass the name of category

```
{props.animal.map(({id, name}, index) =>
  <div key={id}><div>{name}</div><div onClick={() => props.deleteAnimal(index,this.props.category)}>Delete animal</div></div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Code Maniac thanks a lot. I didnt express properly. My doubt is if I have to pass the category or animal down doing something like: <AnimalList deleteAnimal={this.deleteAnimalHandler} animal={this.state.birds} category="cats" /> thanks

Comment: where is that category comming from? you forgot to say where you pass it

Comment: @Peter you should pass it to function `onClick={() => props.deleteAnimal(index,category)}` while mapping

Comment: @Vencovsky i have added already few seconds before you comment mate :)

Comment: if you run the last piece of code, category will get undefined, you need to get it from `this.props.category`

Comment: And to your answer to be complete, you need to add what @Peter wrote in the comments

Comment: @Vencovsky the word category should be considered as example. and as i can see for code from this code op is taking individual element in a category. not sure how the `name` of each category is coming so i left it for `op` to fill in accordingly

Comment: he placed in the first comment of your question how the category is comming, its comming from props as category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189963/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-vencovsky).

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the animal type

`<AnimalList deleteAnimal={this.deleteAnimalHandler} animal={this.state.cats} animalType='cats' />`

And add to the click

`onClick={() => props.deleteAnimal(index, this.props.animalType)`

And implement the `deleteAnimalHandler`

```
deleteAnimalHandler = (index, animalType) => {
    let newAnimals = this.state.animals[animalType].filter((x, i) => i != index)
    let newState = {}
    newState[animalType] = newAnimals
    this.setState(newState)
}
```